# Javascript: image object -> HTML image element

Tags: javascript, html

The code preloads an image into an image object and then (supposed to) set it to the image element src on HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var oImage = new Image();
            oImage.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('myImage').src = oImage;
                alert('done');
            };
            oImage.src = 'image1.jpg';
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="myImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Where is your 'image1.jpg' located? Is it in the same folder as your HTML file?

Comment: yes. I'm testing it locally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script language="javascript">
        window.onload = function () {

            var oImage = new Image();

            oImage.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('myImage').src = oImage.src;
                alert('done');

            };

            oImage.src = 'image1.jpg';
        };
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <img id="myImage" src="" />
</body>

</html>
```

You can't set a **src** to an image, you have to set it to the image's **src.** (PS: Added semicolon at the end and changed `.src = oImage` to `.src = oImage.src`)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xPHyb/1/)**

Comment: Yes, this is the solution.
I've just discovered this in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2nPc/2/

Comment: Well, it works. But using the **.src** won't it be loading the image again? I mean, isn't it the same as `document.getElementById('myImage').src='image1.jpg'`? The purpose is to load a bunch of images in advance. (prelodaing)

Comment: Browsers usually save all loaded images locally after loading them once to prevent reloading images every time you load a page within a website. And preloading an image using JavaScript just adds the image to that local directory. Your browser should do the rest.
Also during the session your JavaScript image is loaded in the browser cache.

Comment: Lol, my fiddle was wrong; it was wrapped in a `window.onload`.  Use this: http://jsfiddle.net/xPHyb/1/

Comment: @MarvinBrouwer , in my case for example... all browsers here are set to store 0 cache on disk. But I think the browser will have it preloaded it in RAM anyway...

Comment: @MarvinBrouwer: is it any better than: `<img id="myImagePreloader1" src="image1.jpg" /><img id="myImagePreloader2" src="image2.jpg" /><img id="myImagePreloader3" src="image3.jpg" />` and set them style to `display: none`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it works the same. the beauty of having it in JavaScript anyways is that you can assign the image to a variable and reuse it.   

Also, if you want to use hidden images your not really easily able to check if they are loaded in contrary of JavaScript