# Why does my image preloading method work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas, theory

**My Question**

The goal is to make sure all images are fully loaded before a new game can begin. My second solution (Fiddle B) achieves this goal more consistently and accurately than my first solution (Fiddle A). **Why?**

### [**JSFIDDLE A**](http://jsfiddle.net/erxqnj4u/)

### [**JSFIDDLE B**](http://jsfiddle.net/q27zje41/)

**Methods**

Here is what both of my fiddle solutions do to preload images:

- There is an array of absolute image URLS for all of the assets required by the game
- The init() function has a for loop which generates a new canvas Image() per URL in the array
- Each newly created image is pushed into another array
- So, we now have the first array containing URL strings, and a second array containing 'HTMLImageElement' objects

Fiddle B differs from Fiddle A, in that it utilises the '.onload' event, plus a counter. The two fiddles use different ways of checking to see if all the image assets have loaded:

**Fiddle A:** compares the length of the two arrays. If they match, start the game

```
for (var i = 0; i < allGameImageUrls.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = allGameImageUrls[i];
        allGameImages.push(img);
        console.log(allGameImages.length);
        if (allGameImages.length >= allGameImageUrls.length) {
            setUpGame();
        } else {
            // images haven't loaded yet
            console.log('STILL LOADING');
            STAGE.fillText("Loading ...", 20, 400);
        }
    }
```

**Fiddle B:** compares the second array length with the counter variable. This counter goes up by 1 every time an image's '.onload' event completes.

```
for (var i = 0; i < allGameImageUrls.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        assetCount++;
        console.log('assetCount = ' + assetCount);
        setUpGame();
    };
    img.src = allGameImageUrls[i];
    allGameImages.push(img);
}
```

**My Question Expanded**

Fiddle A frequently (but not always) triggers the start of a new game before the full list of image assets has been properly loaded, causing game errors. Fiddle B consistently loads all of the image assets before allowing a new game to start. This can be seen in both fiddles from the 'Fully loaded' messages written to the canvas.

Although I can see that Fiddle A works better than Fiddle B, I don't understand why it is superior. Not all tutorials relating to loading HTMLImageElements use '.onload', and the tutorials that don't use it seem perfectly adequate.

Additionally, I don't understand why comparing the lengths of two arrays is not as accurate as comparing the second array length to a counter.

I understand **how** the two solutions differ, but I want to know **why** solution B works better than solution A.

**Previous Research**

Here are just a few examples of previous research I have done in order to try to answer my own question.

- [An article on pre-loading images](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object) which doesn't have any reference to an .onload event
- The accepted solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954400/javascript-image-object-html-image-element) does not use .onload event, but it still works
- The accepted solution to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205874/preloading-images-object-htmlimageelement) is very similar to my Fiddle B (although I discovered it much later). However, the explanation of the solution hasn't helped me to answer my own question.

Comment: Well-written question, +1!

Comment: You say it does, but I can't see it.. Where is fiddle A checking that the image has been loaded? AFAIK you can't tell if an image is downloaded without using the load event.

Comment: @Malk, fiddle A assumes that if the length of the image object array matches the length of the URL array, the images must have loaded. The logic of this is flawed, but at the time I didn't notice because the game I created using this code still worked (except for the problems described in the question).

Comment: You see now that just creating the HTMLImageElements does not mean the image is downloaded and ready to use (which happens asynchronously). Also, I checked all your links and they all make use of onload.

Comment: @Malk you're right about the links. I'm not sure how I missed that the first time around, I've spent quite a while reading up on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two very different approaches: sequential with `for` (which is incorrect) and event-based.

Image downloading is asynchronous process so when the image `src` property is set the browser starts downloading it. It can be, however, very fast especially if the image was already had been downloaded by the browser and cached internally (in fact, it is blazingly fast). So when the next iteration starts it is already available (or, at least, almost all of them are available at the end of the loop). But if you clear the cache or use incognito mode and download them from the remote location (not your local server) then boom! - the loop ends with no image downloaded at all.

Another approach slightly better but the game is set up for every image downloaded, which is probably do not what is required.

Consider the following approach:

```
var length = allGameImageUrls.length,
    count = 0;

var i, img;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        count++;
        // count is increased on every callback
        // so if number of executed callbacks equals
        // the number of images then all the images
        // are downloaded
        if (count === length) {
            setUpGame();
        }
    };
    img.src = allGameImageUrls[i];
    allGameImages.push(img);
}
```

The only drawback is if one of the images does not exist, the game never starts so you need to workaround it with timeout.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation has helped. Thanks for the heads up too - I'll test it with an image that doesn't exist and work on a solution.